# Connect html boxes with broken lines using css and SVG

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I need to connect divs with broken line like below

[image]

I tried to do this using the following plugin [jquery plugin to connect html elements](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Connect-HTML-Elements-with-Lines-HTML-SVG-Connect.html)  but it connects elemets with a direct line, It doesn't seem to be very customizable.

Considering that it should be responsive, is it possible? any idea?

This is basic html structure:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #808080;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.lighter {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:800px;margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="container darker" id="one">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </p>
  </div>
  <div class="container lighter" id="two">
    <p>div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container darker" id="three">
    <p>div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container lighter" id="four">
    <p>div 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my attempt to create an SVG for connecting the boxes:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300px">
  <rect width="5" height="20" fill="black"/>
  <path d="M 0 10 h 70 v 40 h -70" fill="none" stroke="black"  />
  <rect y="40" width="5" height="20" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

But how can I combine the HMTL/CSS with this SVG?

Comment: With `SVG` you could do this but it would not be a trivial task if you have no experience of SVG

Comment: Could you provide the basic HTML structure and relevant CSS (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because the way the elements are offset may have a bearing on what we can do easily.

Comment: I added basic html structure

Comment: Could you describe more what you want the dimensions to be. You have set a max width but what is the min width. And how are the boxes to be sized in relation to it.

Comment: ok, I need to show a text with aproximately 220 charachter in the divs, so I think min width:250px is suitable, also I updated html